# Schema Markup, having a ItemList in a FAQ Answer

Tags: schema.org

According to the Schema Markup docs https://schema.org/acceptedAnswer 
an ItemList can be a thing inserted in an answer of a FAQ question. But I am kinda confused on how to insert an ItemList as a answer of a question like:

```
      {
            "@type": "Question",
            "name": "test?",
            "acceptedAnswer": {
                "@type": "ItemList",
                "name": "Test ItemList",
                "itemListElement": [
                    {
                        "@type": "ListItem",
                        "position": 1,
                        "item": {
                            "@type": "MusicGroup",
                            "name": "Beatles"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```